# Controlling refraction with MeshStandardMaterial

Tags: three.js

So I have very basic setup:

```
var cubeCamera = new THREE.CubeCamera (1, 1000, 1024);
cubeCamera.renderTarget.texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter;
cubeCamera.renderTarget.texture.mapping = THREE.CubeRefractionMapping;
cubeCamera.updateCubeMap (renderer, scene);

var matte = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    envMap: cubeCamera.renderTarget.texture,
    metalness: 0.5,
    roughness: 0.4
});
```

and this creates correctly blurred refraction. However, driving metalness to 0 makes it vanish almost completely, making the material seem fully opaque. What is correct way to set up matte refractive material?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use `MeshStandardMaterial` to create a translucent and refractive non-metallic material. You are setting `metalness` to zero, or near zero.

Non-metals typically have a low specular reflectance. That means the specular reflections from the environment are minimal — certainly compared to metals. Consequently, `MeshStandardMaterial` has been designed to have similar properties.

You have two options.

The first option is to compensate by increasing `material.envMapIntensity`, which defaults to 1. This simulates a brighter environment.

A second option is to use the more feature-rich `MeshPhysicalMaterial`, instead.

`MeshPhysicalMaterial` has an additional `material.reflectivity` property which controls the specular reflectance for non-metals. For physically-based materials, setting this property to 1 is a reasonable maximum value, but you can increase it further if you want.

three.js r.86

Comment: I tried physical/reflectivity before I posted this, the result is very much lke metalness > 0. envMapIntensity is not nice solution either since it oversaturates the colors. I wish phong material (used in examples for refraction) had roughness setting.

Comment: hmm, maybe I can do that with noise normal map?